# Replace string in paragraph while keeping style docx library

Tags: python, docx

I am replacing the strings in tables and paragraphs of word document. However the styles change. How can I keep original style format?

```
with open(r"C:\Users\y.Israfilbayov\Desktop\testfiles\test_namedranges\VariableNames.json") as p:
                data = json.load(p)

document = Document(r"C:\Users\y.Israfilbayov\Desktop\testfiles\test_namedranges_update\F10352-JB117-FMXXX Pile XXXX As-built Memo GAIA Auto trial_v6.docx")

for key, value in data.items():
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if key in paragraph.text:
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(str(key), str(value))
for key, value in data.items():
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    if key in paragraph.text:
                        paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace(str(key),str(value))
```

There was a similar post, however it did not help me (maybe I did something wrong).

Comment: What similar post? This is the internet; give a _link_!

Comment: I have found the solution.There is no need for the additional "run" looping for preserving the format. the main point is to save a style in the top menu of the word document and refresh it with a right-click. IF someone would have difficulty, I can assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should meet your needs. Requires docx2python 2.0.0+

```
from docx2python.utilities import replace_docx_text

replace_docx_text(
    input_filename,
    output_filename,
    ("Apples", "Bananas"),  # replace Apples with Bananas
    ("Pears", "Apples"),  # replace Pears with Apples
    ("Bananas", "Pears"),  # replace Bananas with Pears
    html=True,
)
```

You may have a problem if your replacement strings include tabs or symbols, but "regular" text replacement will work and preserve *most*[1] formatting.

To allow this, docx2python will not replace text strings where formatting changes, e.g., "part of **this string** is bold", unless you specify `html=False`, in which case strings will be replaced regardless of format, and some formatting will be lost.

[1] The following will be preserved:

- italic
- bold
- underline
- strike
- superscript
- subscript
- small caps
- all caps
- highlighted
- font size
- colored text
- (some others, but not guaranteed)

Edit for follow-up question, how do I replace marker text in tables?

My workflow for doing this is to keep all formatting in Word. That is, I create a template in Word, slice out the context I need, then put everything back together like a puzzle.

This github "project" is an example (one file) of how I replace text in tables (where the tables can be any size).

https://github.com/ShayHill/replace_docx_tables

Comment: Thank you very much, just for single script it worked. Is it possible to replace with this script within table and cells?i will need to iterate and add values from json file for the replacement.

Comment: It is not possible with the same workflow. There are other Python libraries (e.g., python-docx) which build some structure and insert it into Word documents. This is not how I work, so I haven't tried them. When doing what you're doing now, I create a docx file that looks the way I like, unzip, create a template from document.xml, put everything back together like a puzzle with my table cells wrapped in the appropriate xml documents, zip it back up into a *.docx.

Comment: @Yusif99, see my edit for help with tables and cells.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answers! to be honest I struggle to understand your code(probably because lac of the knowledge). I found out that adding "run loop" can help keeping formatting. However in my case it is not working properly. I have tried with many different templates(sometime it works sometime not). I would appreciate if you can assist!

Answer (score 0):

In the docx library documentation located at
https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/text.html#paragraph-objects, it states the following regarding assigning a value to paragraph.text :

"Assigning text to this property causes all existing paragraph content to be replaced with a single run containing the assigned text. ... **Paragraph-level formatting, such as style, is preserved.** **All run-level formatting, such as bold or italic, is removed.** "

Are the changes in style you are observing consistent with that?
If so, then perhaps you are loosing the "run" objects with their specific styling that are children of the paragraph object.  In that case, **you might be better of adding another level to your loop to iterate through all the paragraph.runs and replace the text on those individually**.

For example, once you have the paragraph, then

```
for run in paragraph.runs:
    if key in run.text:
        run.text = run.text.replace(str(key), str(value))
```

Comment: for key, value in data.items():
    for table in document.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        if "Pile" in run.text:
                            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace("Pile",str(value))                                              Thanks for your comment.Wrote in the way above. However again , it changes the script. In my case i do not need to preserve bold and italic. However the script itself makes it bold.

Comment: I am just adding another loop(run loop) to the script, however, the interesting bit is that sometimes it is not replacing and sometimes it is omitting the text after I save it to a new doc.

Comment: I have tried many times by editing the word document. Sometimes it works sometime not. Can not understand , what is the reason of not replacing properly. without "run looping" Iit works fine, but as I mentioned makes the formatting default(do not keep formatting).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @property
> def text(self):
>     """
>     String formed by concatenating the text of each run in the paragraph.
>     Tabs and line breaks in the XML are mapped to ``\\t`` and ``\\n``
>     characters respectively.
>
>     Assigning text to this property causes all existing paragraph content
>     to be replaced with a single run containing the assigned text.
>     A ``\\t`` character in the text is mapped to a ``<w:tab/>`` element
>     and each ``\\n`` or ``\\r`` character is mapped to a line break.
>     Paragraph-level formatting, such as style, is preserved. All
>     run-level formatting, such as bold or italic, is removed.
>     """
>     text = ''
>     for run in self.runs:
>         text += run.text
>     return text
> ```

From the [documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/docx/text/paragraph.html) it looks like the Styles should stay the same however; bold/italic formatting can be removed.

If this is the formatting you are trying to preserve, you may need to identify what run the key is in first then modify it.